# SQL query stack trace of execution

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is there a way to get the stack trace of the sql query that is given in awr, i mean a way to check the flow of the query from which package or procedure that it has been triggered? tkprof and awr both show only the sql and the elspased time, parse and fetches. –

Comment: anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

As far I know - there are no other way than full code search - either select from Oracle internal views (USER_SOURCE/ALL_SOURCE/DBA_SOURCE):

```
SELECT name, text
FROM dba_source
WHERE lower(text) LIKE ('%some representative text from query%)
```

or text search in code repository, if you have it.